# Difference between Clean Price, Dirty Price and NPV using QuantLib Python

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance, quantlib, financialinstrument

I used QuantLib Python to price a fixed rate bond.

I used `ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA, schedule)` to ensure that cash flows are the same for each coupon payment period.

For discounting, I used `ql.Actual360()` as day count convention.

My codes are as follows:

```
import QuantLib as ql
valuationDate = ql.Date(30, 6, 2020)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = valuationDate
schedule = ql.Schedule(ql.Date(7, 5, 2016), ql.Date(15, 8, 2024), ql.Period(ql.Semiannual), ql.NullCalendar(), ql.Following, ql.Following, ql.DateGeneration.Forward, True)
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(0, 100, schedule, [0.05], ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA, schedule))
curve = ql.FlatForward(valuationDate, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.05)), ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded)
handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve)
bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(handle)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)
irr = fixedRateBond.bondYield(fixedRateBond.NPV(), ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, valuationDate)
print('NPV:', fixedRateBond.NPV())
print('IRR:', irr)
print('Clean Price:', fixedRateBond.cleanPrice(irr, ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, valuationDate))
print('Dirty Price:', fixedRateBond.dirtyPrice(irr, ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, valuationDate))
print('Accrued Interest:', fixedRateBond.accruedAmount(ql.Date(30, 6, 2020)))
```

The results I get are as follows:

```
NPV: 100.59728065053405
IRR: 0.04743504524230957
Clean Price: 100.59728133098947
Dirty Price: 101.3309769831634
Accrued Interest: 0.7336956521739156
```

As far as I know, the NPV should be the same as the dirty price. However, there is a minor difference that I cannot get rid of. Grateful if someone could explain where I went wrong.

And when I subtract the clean price from the dirty price to manually obtain the accrued interest, the answer is 0.7336956521739211, which differs slightly from QuantLib's `accruedAmount` function. Can someone explain where I went wrong please?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the irr to calculate the clean and dirty prices instead of the yield?

Comment: @Darnoc What do you mean by yield? The coupon rate of 5%?

Comment: My apologies, I think that the dirty price should be equal to the NPV. If you can help, grateful to provide assistance. If ever I'm wrong in what I'm saying, please feel free to correct me directly.

Comment: Yes, the IRR is less than the coupon rate that’s why the dirty price less the clean price is greater than the accrued amount function result. This is also why your NPV is likely less than your clean price?

Comment: "NPV should be the same as the clean price" has been changed to "NPV should be the same as the dirty price".

Comment: Therefore, I should write ```print('Clean Price:', fixedRateBond.cleanPrice(0.05 ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, valuationDate))``` instead?

Comment: This is what I get if I change the rate in the ```cleanPrice``` function and ```dirtyPrice``` function from the IRR to 0.05: ```NPV: 100.59728065053405
IRR: 0.04743504524230957
Clean Price: 99.63602541352493
Dirty Price: 100.36972106569885
Accrued Interest: 0.7336956521739156``` The difference is still there

Comment: You don't need to pass parameters to the dirty price and clean price methods if you are supplying a pricing engine to your bond object.

Comment: Or you can pass the yield and other parameters with a null pricing engine.

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/pricing-a-fixedratebond-in-quantlib-yield-vs-termstructure/12715#12715

Comment: Mixing of day count conventions also seems to be an issue.

Comment: Since I have supplied a pricing engine, I did not pass any parameters to the ```cleanPrice``` and the ```dirtyPrice``` functions. However, the issue remains: ```NPV: 100.59947845040405
IRR: 0.04687152397836583
Clean Price: 99.86593245380611
Dirty Price: 100.64038897554524
Accrued Interest: 0.7744565217391309```. Maybe the issue lies in the day count conventions indeed

Comment: What was the logic in using different conventions?

Comment: ```ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA, schedule)``` is used to obtain fixed cash flows for the fixed rate bond. Refer to following [link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36532/pricing-a-fixed-rate-bond-in-quantlib-python). ```ql.Actual360()``` is used to generate the coupon payment dates, given that coupon payment frequency is semiannual.

Comment: Did you review the link I posted previously? I assume the information contained there should have provided a solution.

Comment: I got the answer from quant.stackexchange.com https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/66419/difference-arising-between-dirty-price-and-npv-using-quantlib-python/66426#66426